# when to use Sequel::Dataset as to Sequel::Model

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm new to Ruby's Sequel and am curious as to when I should use `Sequel::Dataset` and when is best to use `Sequel::Model`.

Comment: This isn't a good question, because it entails too many possible questions/choices/reasons why you'd want to use one over the other. Simply put, use datasets for small code and models for big code, but that's hardly a good and complete guideline. Why you'd want to do that will take a lot of 'splainin'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a first-class model, you should be using the model. This provides features like validations, callbacks before and after state transitions and events, as well as a centralized place to store business logic.

A dataset is generally used for more low-level operations.